# Consulta sobre sumar y agrupar con condición

Tags: sql-server

me estoy aventurando en SQL Server y no he logrado hacer lo que necesito, Tengo esta tabla con reporte diario y necesito hacer una consulta que agrupe el SKU por semana y que La columna EnTransferencia que muestre sea solo el del día domingo.

Muchas gracias de antemano

[image: Listado Columnas]

[image: Resultado]

Comment: tienes algún catalogo de dias?

Comment: Eso que estas mostrando no tiene ningun tipo de agrupacion. es solo mostrar el dia 7 de cada semana..

Comment: en la columna de inventario solo necesito que muestre el del dia 7, pero que agrupe los nombres

Comment: @ManuelValdivieso no hay nada que agrupar, es siempre el mismo nombre...

Comment: Esto es muy diferente a lo que estaba antes...

Comment: ahí esta la imagen, lo hice así porque el real es mucho mas grande

Comment: @ManuelValdivieso Perfecto. siempre revisa las preguntas. en la anterior no habia nada que agrupar, ahora si hay una agrupacion obvia. Podrias agregar cualquier cosa que hayas intentado y no haya funcionado?

Comment: Intente hacer esto pero no funciona SELECT      
     Semana
    ,Nombre    
    ,SUM(CASE Inventario WHEN Dia = '1' AND Inventario = 0 
                         WHEN Dia = '2' AND Inventario = 0 
                         WHEN Dia = '3' AND Inventario = 0 
                         WHEN Dia = '4' AND Inventario = 0 
                         WHEN Dia = '5' AND Inventario = 0 
                         WHEN Dia = '6' AND Inventario = 0 
              ELSE Inventario END) as Inventario_Semanal,
     FROM [Definitiva].[dbo].[00000000]
     group by Semana, Nombre
     order by Semana

Comment: Sacaste el resultado esperado, y esos datos son todos iguales. No se como podemos ayudarte con tan poca informacion...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es algo como esto:

```
    Select ID, Año, Mes, Semana, Dia, Fecha, Nombre, Inventario 
    FROM Tabla Where Dia = 7 Order by semana asc
```

Comment: Mas alla que es correcta la respuesta (o sea, ese codigo esta bien), yo hubiera esperado, OP parece confundido y no se si realmente esto sea la solucion.

Comment: Y ahora OP actualizco su pregunta. y tu respuesta quedo mal.

Comment: Ok compañero, tienes razón, supuse que lo que pedía era sencillo pero en realidad es porqué no proporcionan toda la información. Gracias por el consejo.

Comment: Tenes reputacion suficiente para dejar un comentario y preguntarle a OP si realmente eso es el problema.. aprovechalo ;)

Answer (score -2):

Vamos a hacer una tabla que haga la agrupacion.. y despues otra tabla que devuelva el resto de los registros.

Cuando uno hace una agrupación, todos los campos o forman parte de la agrupacion, o son una función de agrupacion (o sea, agrupo y con todos los datos de esa columna, tengo que hacer algo, seleccionar el maximo, minimo, contarlos, lo que sea)

Para ello, primero hagamos un query que agrupe:

```
Select año,mes,semana,nombre, Max(dia) as maxdia
From Tabla
Group by año,mes,semana,nombre
```

Esto, nos va a devolver un solo registro por la agrupacion año,mes,semana,nombre (que es lo que queremos agrupar) y el maximo dia que encontramos ahi (que esperemos, sea siempre el domingo).

Ahora, para obtener los otros datos, vamos a unir esta tabla a si misma, con la relacion de join de todos esos campos.

```
Select b.Id, a.año, a.mes, a.semana, a.maxdia as dia, b.fecha, a.nombre, b.inventario
From Tabla as b innerjoin (
        Select año,mes,semana,nombre, Max(dia) as maxdia
        From Tabla
        Group by año,mes,semana,nombre) as a 
    ON a.año = b.año And a.mes = b.mes And a.semana = b.semana And a.nombre = b.nombre
```

Comment: Cuando ingreso el MAX(dia) me esta retornando el 4 y el 2 pero no el 7, me asegure que en la columna solo hay valores entre el 1 y el 7

Comment: No puedo contestarte eso sin ver los datos con los que estas trabajando. Este query funciona sobre los datos de arriba.. si por ejemplo en tus datos reales, no siempre se llega la 7, hay que cambiarlo.

Comment: Actualice las imagenes con la tabla real que es